# Python: Structuring a list of code using pygeoip

Tags: python, list

this will be a very nooby situation that really I just need help structuring certain code. I'm trying to use a geoIP python package to use a list of IPs that will return the location of the IP for a project I'm doing.

I followed a few install guides and example code and it's currently coded as:

```
import pygeoip
rawdata = pygeoip.GeoIP('/usr/local/GeoLiteCity.dat')

def ipquery(ip):
      data = rawdata.record_by_name(ip)
      country = data['country_name']
      city = data['city']
      print '[x] '+str(city)+',' +str(country)

ip='1.22.143.64'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.23.62.193'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.39.46.10'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.39.61.207'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.39.62.172'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.39.63.160'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
ip='1.39.80.81'
ipquery(ip)
print ip
```

Returns as:

```
[x] Bhandup,India
1.22.143.64
[x] Bhandup,India
1.23.62.193
[x] Mumbai,India
1.39.46.10
```

etc.

I do like how it returns and prefer it this way, however, I have over 200 IPs to look up. Is there a way to list these without ruining the code? I've tried listing them already but it only results in errors. I'm not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a text file, say, "addresses.txt" and do:

```
with open("addresses.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ip = line.strip()
        if ip:
            ipquery(ip)
            print ip
```